# How do I set up proxy server for my network having D-Link 2750U modem router

Tags: proxy, adsl-router, dsl-modem

I want to install proxy server for my network and all I have is a D-Link 2750U  modem router and a spare computer.  We are a start up and at the moment can't afford a better router for web-filtering purposes. I am trying to set this up because someone in the office is consuming all the bandwidth. I have no idea how to do it or even if it's possible with this modem router.

Please help me out and guide me through the whole process.

Comment: If you are trying to identify the culprit who is using all your bandwidth you could use the modem's syslog as this will tell you what website the user has requested and which of the machines on the LAN (by MAC address and IP assigned) it is, you should then be able to find the person using the computer.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of free, open-source proxy server solutions out there. A free (community edition) solution I have used before is Endian Firewall. It is a complete operating system so will wipe your disk, but it has a complete web GUI.

Other alternatives you could install Linux onto the machine and use one of the many proxy server packages on the net...

The setup will then be:

`Modem/Router ==> Proxy server PC (2 x Ethernet NICs) ==> Network switch ==> Office computers`

Answer (score 1):

It can be done but its not exactly easy.

Windows Server has a proxy service which most recently was called Fore Front Threat Management Gateway but I believe has been removed completely now from support.

Anyway there are two ways, to run a 'true' web proxy you can setup the proxy on that spare computer, plug in to the network on a static IP and change all users proxy settings in internet options to hit that hostname/IP. The second way is to use it more as a firewall by running it similarly to how I do in my lab which is install two NIC's on that spare computer, run one to the router and one to the network (switch) change your DHCP gateway address to use the IP address of the network (switch) NIC. This way all traffic runs through the spare computer and the free firewall tool you have on it, this way you can control bandwidth and limits, etc.

Have a look at freeproxy for first option and pfsense for second.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible without using extra PC. I have once tried to set-up schedule-based firewall/proxy on similar D-Link box using OpenWRT OSS firmware, but failed. I had not enough time to play with it and proved fairly difficult as since 90s I was no longer involved with complex router configurations. Here is a handful of links that may help:

OpenWRT home - https://openwrt.org/

(old) proxy list for OpenWRT - https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/proxy.overview

Now I would try other, more user friendly open firmware, here are 2 relevant articles:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_router_firmware_projects

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/top-6-alternative-firmwares-router/

And finally - please make a simple HowTo - and let us know. The World will be grateful and your fame will shine through the ages ;-)